# Nethereum Getting TransactionHash of SendTransaction

Tags: transactions, nethereum

I am using Nethereum for Unity3d and I have managed to muddle my way through a lot of issues, but I have a huge problem I just can't seem to solve.

I can get this to work with signed transaction requests (SignAndSendTransaction), however when integrating with MetaMask it seems to be a whole different ballgame.

My code is as follows:

```
var spendRequest = new EthCallUnityRequest(_url);
var transactionInput = tokenContractService.CreateSpendTransactionInput(accountAddress, new HexBigInteger(amountToSpend), new HexBigInteger(50000), new HexBigInteger(25), new HexBigInteger(0));
Debug.Log("Sending transaction...");
var sendTransactionRequest = SendTransaction(transactionInput.To, transactionInput.Data);

var transactionReceiptPolling = new TransactionReceiptPollingRequest(_url);
Debug.Log("Waiting for result...");
yield return transactionReceiptPolling.PollForReceipt(sendTransactionRequest, 2);
spentSuccess = true;
```

It flows sort of like this:

- user presses a button to spend some stuff.
- When they press the button, MetaMask pops up and asks the user to confirm they want to send the gas and such
- That popup happens when SendTransaction is called (fourth line).
- Program *should* wait for the user to click confirm, and for the transaction to be mined before continuing (it doesnt, i just get error)

I have also tried doing a "yield return new SendTransaction(...)" but I didn't know how to store the transaction hash from doing that... so i ended up with line 4.

The program needs to get the transaction hash of that transaction to be able to poll for the success (so that it spins inside a coroutine until it is successful and we can all move on).

Here is my output:

```
UnityLoader.js:4  Sending transaction... 
UnityLoader.js:4 (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
UnityLoader.js:4 
blob:https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/f17f9204-09dd-4f19-9177-12b9f92f95a0:2 0x82a9b48b2759411d7598462051451fecc9061c216379596d53309c2c121223b5
UnityLoader.js:4 Waiting for result...
UnityLoader.js:4  
UnityLoader.js:4 (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
UnityLoader.js:4 
UnityLoader.js:4 ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
UnityLoader.js:4 Parameter name: transactionHash
UnityLoader.js:4   at Nethereum.RPC.Eth.Transactions.EthGetTransactionReceipt.BuildRequest (System.String transactionHash, System.Object id) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have run out of ideas! I know (I think) the problem lies in the fact that the transaction isn't "sent" until the user presses "confirm" but the code is all like "meh who cares, its done, lets continue".

Any help would be super appreciated, or even a finger point in another place I might ask this to get help.

Thank you for your time!